# How do you copy imported sql values in a table into a text box?

Tags: php, html

I have created a table and am pulling data from mySQL database. I have created 3 columns and would like to take the 3rd column (suggested quantity) and copy those values into a row of text boxes in the 4th column, (order quantity) so they could be edited by a user. How do I do this?

```
$sql = "SELECT item_price.item_id, item_price.ITEM_NAME,suggested_qty,Price_item
FROM item_price JOIN suggested_item  
ON item_price.ITEM_NAME = suggested_item.ITEM_NAME";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>


<tr>
<th> ID</th>
<th>Item Name</th>
<th>Suggested Quantity</th>
<th>Order Quantity</th>
<th>Total Cost ($)</th>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['item_id'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ITEM_NAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['suggested_qty'] . "</td>";
}
?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by wrapping the table in a form and add a column with a input text field with the suggested quantity. Something like this should get you started:

```
$sql = "SELECT item_price.item_id, item_price.ITEM_NAME,suggested_qty,Price_item
FROM item_price JOIN suggested_item  
ON item_price.ITEM_NAME = suggested_item.ITEM_NAME";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<form action="#" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<th> ID</th>
<th>Item Name</th>
<th>Suggested Quantity</th>
<th>Order Quantity</th>
<th>Total Cost ($)</th>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['item_id'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ITEM_NAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['suggested_qty'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='editedvalues[]' value='" . $row['suggested_qty'] . "' /></td>";
    echo "<td>total</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>

</table>
</form>
```

You should add a javascript onchange listener to the input fields to calculate a total price for each row and show it to the user.